# Why can't I pass a jquery selector oject to a function from an inline HTML Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an unexpected error in which I am having a slightly annoying time debugging.
The error I get is this:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="search" action="search" method="get">
<input type="text" id="search-string" />
<button type="button" onclick="return clearInputValue( $("#search-string") )">
<span class="clear-icon"></span>
</button>
</form>

 <script>
 var  clearInputValue = function(a) {

 // Ultimately I will check if the object passed to this function has a value greater than 1, and if so, I will clear the input

   return false;

 };

 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different set of quotes.

```
<button type="button" onclick="return clearInputValue( $('#search-string') )">
```

Note the single quotes.

Also, as a side note, inline javascript is discouraged. It's much better to keep your content (html) separated from your behaviour (javascript), just as you do with your presentation (css).

Answer (score 2):

For one, you just terminated the string early. Change it to:

```
onclick="return clearInputValue($('#search-string'))"
```

Second, you should attach events using jQuery instead.

```
$(function(){

    function clearInputValue(a) {
        return false;
    };


    $('button').on('click',function(){
        clearInputValue($('#search-string'));
    });

});
```